# Pass the value of one argument to multiple functions within a function wrapper

Tags: r, function, wrapper

I am trying to write a function wrapper to make multiple plots within the same chart. The function that I use is `plotCI()` in 'gplots' package

```
sprPlot = function(data.frame, condition, ...){
require(gplots)
for(i in 1:condition){
    if(i == 1) 
       plotCI(...)
    else 
       plotCI(add = T, ...)
}
```

However, as you can see, since there are basically two plotCI()s, if I try to set some of the arguments in `plotCI()` - e.g. `pch = -`, I get an error message saying that the formal argument pch matches multiple arguments in the function. I wonder if there is any way to get around it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a complete use case (including example data and the `sprPlot` call) and the error that is given?

Comment: @BrianDiggs Thank you for the reply. For some reason, the error message was gone after I made some changes to the script...Since I made several changes, I am not sure which change was responsible for getting rid of the problem...